# Debug and find error "Error converting data type varchar to real"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am assigned with a task to debug an existing ASP.NET C# system. I found out that this is caused by a stored procedure, and the error message is

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5
>   Error converting data type varchar to real.

No line numbers or any description of errors. Any kind of heads up is appreciated. Where should I look into, How to debug so that to find exact error. Please help.

Comment: Looks like issue with sql from procedure. Look at the query and find the columns which are `varchar` type performing operation with `number` type. It might be where condition also or join with string and number you have to look for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error, sharing my answer hoping someone is facing the same problem. This is where the error was

```
CASE [Category].[ID]
    WHEN '1' THEN [Category].[Name]
    WHEN '2' THEN [Category].[Weight]
END
```

Here `[Category].[Name]` is string and `[Category].[Weight]` is real, trying different data types inside the same `CASE` clause, so to solve this all what I had to do is split this condition, like this

```
CASE [Category].[ID]
    WHEN '1' THEN [Category].[Name]
    END,
CASE [Category].[ID]
    WHEN '2' THEN [Category].[Weight]
END
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

The problem is obvious -- you have a string and you are treating it as a number. There are three possible reasons.

The first is an explicit conversion where the string is converted to a number. This should be easy to find. You can replace the explicit conversion with `try_convert()` in SQL Server 2012+.

The second is not much harder. The `+` operator is used both for addition and string concatenation. It often causes this type of problem. All numeric arguments need to be converted to strings. Or, change all code that does concatenation to use the `CONCAT()` function -- the arguments are automatically converted to strings.

The third is implicit conversion for numeric operations. If you have any other operations (or function calls) that require numeric values, then SQL Server will implicitly convert the values to numbers. This can be very hard to find. Try to write code that does not rely on implicit conversions.

Note: Trying to filter out bad values using a `WHERE` clause (even in a subquery or CTE) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply debug your sql code as you do in Visual Studio if you have Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

[image]

You can start debugging, Debug -> Start Debugging or using the icon shown in the picture or even using a keyboard shortcut Alt + F5.

I would recommend to write the execute statement in a different query window, with parameters if necessary, don't forget to add your db call  and debug this window.

```
use yourdb
exec yoursp para1 para2
```

You can Step Into (F11) and Step Over (F10). The place where the debugging stops or crash is the place you have to look into. You can even put brake points when once you start debugging using keyboard shortcut F9. [For more look at this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlRNA8pmfIk)